# Mongoose updateMany does not seem to work as expected in version ^8.0.3

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I wrote a simple updateMany statement to add a now field in a collection called products.  As new products may not have an onSale property it may be added to the first time when those products now become eligible for onSale.  However, older products which had already been onSale need to be update with onSale:false. Here is my update statement. I need to update the onSale: false when the sale ends for products.
I also notice that version 8.0.3 no longer accepts the {multi:true} anymore.

```js
     public async updateProductsToOnSale(productIds: Array<string>, onSaleStatus: boolean): Promise<UpdateWriteOpResult | undefined> {
        try {
            return await Product.updateMany(
                {
                    _id: {
                        $in: productIds
                    }
                },
                { $set: { onSale: onSaleStatus } },            )
        } catch (error) {
            this.logger.error(error,`Update Failed for productIds  ${productIds}`);
        }
    }
```

The behavior I see that sometimes no rows are updated. However, when I print out the matched count I get matchedCount:1 even though the update did not work.  Will this update work for setting a new onSale property as well as for an existing onSale property? If not is there a way to accomplish that with one updateMany or do I need 2 , one for the existing onSale and another to set a new onSale property? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No,You don't need two function, you can use [bulkWrite](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/)

```
let bulkUpdateOps = products.map(function(doc) { // you can warp this into your function
    return {
        "updateOne": {
            "filter": { "_id": doc.id },
            "update": { "$set": { onSale: true} },
            "upsert": true
        }
    };
});

Product.bulkWrite(bulkUpdateOps); // for mongoose model instance
```

[Mongoose bulk write doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.bulkWrite)

Comment: I am using Mongoose so I cannot use db.collection. Mongoose works by using the instance of the schema Model

Comment: @BreenDeen I have changed the code according to mongooose

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this with one `updateMany()` function if you use an [Aggregation Pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/).

Using `$set` without a query condition as the first parameter will add the `onSale` property to every document and by using a `$cond` you can specify which documents will be set to `onSaleStatus` via an `$in` operator.

If an `_id` is `$in` your array of `productIds` then set it to  `onSaleStatus` otherwise set it to `false`.

An example would be:

```js
return await Product.updateMany({},
    [ 
        { 
            $set: { 
                onSale: {
                    $cond: {
                        if: {
                            $in: [
                                "$_id",
                                productIds
                            ]
                        },
                        then: onSaleStatus,
                        else: false
                    } 
                }
            } 
        },
    ]
);
```

See [HERE](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/A9aOOLsz4gV) for a full working example.